# UNIX command to search blank word

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

In a file (tab delimited Text, CSV or database file) you have first name, last name and address. In some rows you do not have last name but first name and address is there. How can you list the rows that last name is blank using UNIX command?

FirstName LastName Street      City
Dan,      God,     1st Street, Chicago
Sam,         ,     2nd Street, Chicago
Adam,     Smith,   3rd Street, Chicago

It could be CSV, tab delimited text file(;,:). answer should be 2nd row above.

Comment: How are the names separated?

Comment: Show sample lines from input file.

Comment: tab delimited text or CSV or database file it could be any kind of file we used in ETL process.

Comment: @Dangod Ahhh. You're going to have to write your own code to use "any kind of file" you used in your "ETL process".

Comment: Thank you Elliot Frisch. I can use awk command for ETL tool effectively as I now understand

Comment: This question already answered by 3 experts and I accepts anubhava's answer is most acceptable since it is simple. But also other two answers also very good and addressed my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming input file is CSV, you can use awk:

```
awk -F, '$2 == ""' file
```

to print all the rows where 2nd columns (last name) is blank.

Comment: Thanks Very Much. It is working. For tab delimited file I used awk -F '\t' '$2==""' file it was working

Comment: Great to know, can you mark the answer as accepted now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk 'NF!=3' file
```

it prints all lines where the number of fields is not 3.

Comment: This is short and sweet. I like your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide sample text, I've had to take some guesses about what you're after.

Here's the sample text I'm using:

```
06:33:20 0 1 james@brindle:/tmp$ cat sample.csv
first,last,address,otherstuff
first,,address,otherstuff
first,last,,
```

A simple `grep ,,` doesn't work as it also finds the last line:

```
06:33:22 0 0 james@brindle:/tmp$ grep ,, sample.csv
first,,address,otherstuff
first,last,,
```

Since the first name field is first on the line, we can simplify the problem a little bit: we want to find places where the first comma on the line is immediately followed by a second comma.

```
06:35:07 0 0 james@brindle:/tmp$ grep "^[^,]*,," sample.csv
first,,address,otherstuff
```

In that regex, the first `^` anchors the regex to the start of the line; `[^,]*` matches 0 or more occurrences of any character except the comma (yes, the `^` is doing something very different in this context), and finally `,,` matches the two commas.

If you wanted to look for the 3rd field being empty you'd need to repeat yourself a little bit.

```
06:35:28 0 0 james@brindle:/tmp$ grep "^[^,]*,[^,]*,," sample.csv
first,last,,
```

Here you're looking for 0 or more non-comma characters, followed by a comma, followed by 0 or more non-commas, followed by two commas.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and it is much more helpful and I got more advanced knowledge on grep command. Thank you very much once again.